# Wifi stop working after while on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Yesterday I bought new laptop Lenovo E540 and I installed here Ubuntu 14.04.2. But I've problem with my wifi (router is Dlink g version). I can connect to wifi without problems after turning on laptop. But then (after some time of work) suddenly my connection is lost, but network-manager is still signalizing that I'm connect but I can't even ping anything. When I try to reconnect via manager to my network it's looking like it's trying to connect but it will never do... I have to reboot and then everything is again correct until it will close connection again. I was searching net, but unfortunatily without luck. I tried to comment dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, but nothing happen.

on Jeremy31 suggestion here is a result of

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5028]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b728]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

when I used grep network-manager over syslog I found there some errors:

```
Mar 14 22:40:03 dano-lenovo NetworkManager[784]:  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (3) GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get UID of name ':1.23': no such name
```

but I think it's problem that I can't reconnect, but why this  happend I'm not sure..

last logs before error are:

```
NetworkManager[784]:  (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Mar 14 22:38:31 dano-lenovo NetworkManager[784]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Mar 14 22:38:31 dano-lenovo NetworkManager[784]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Mar 14 22:38:31 dano-lenovo NetworkManager[784]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Mar 14 22:38:31 dano-lenovo wpa_supplicant[909]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
```

Tnaks for help

Comment: What wifi card?  Please edit question to include the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Hello,

thanks for response, I put result to my question.. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 7):

you can try one of the below solution:

Open terminal and type in: `sudo service network-manager restart`.
OR
Go to System Setting -> Network -> Forget your wifi and reconnect to it.
OR
Restart or Log off and Log into your laptop.

Comment: I shouldn't have to do any of your suggestions. Why should it stop working? Are we not looking for a solution where it won't have to stop working, not when it happens, what I should do. Not sure if this answer is any useful

Answer (score 4):

My new Dell Inspiron laptop had the same issue: WiFi would work for a
few minutes, then stop working.  Adding

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` fixed the problem.

But then I saw
[How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)
which seems a more definitive approach.  So I did that instead
(removing `rtl8723be.conf` as well), and that worked as well.

I'm a little uneasy using this "unapproved" WiFi driver, but it does
seem to work.

Comment: Which options did you add and how?

Comment: It is a driver from Realtek. I just made a ppa for it.

Answer (score 0):

This will install backported modules from the 3.19 kernel and it works well

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
cd backports-3.19-rc1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

`echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`
Reboot

If you update and get a new kernel you need to do the following

```
cd backports-3.19-rc1-1
make clean
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

EDIT: after seeing the wireless-info, I would change the encryption to WPA2 only with no TKIP

After changing encryption, if you want to try it without the backports `cd ~/backports-3.19-rc1-1` and then `sudo make uninstall` reboot and if you feel it works better with the backports `cd ~/backports-3.19-rc1-1` and `sudo make install`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it... Can you tell me what is wrong now that is not working that I've to install backported modules? I'm just wondering what is wrong, because there was no problem on my previous laptop on lower ubuntu version.

Comment: Not exactly sure but it seems to be an issue with every ubuntu kernel lately

Comment: Still not working. After reboot it happend again. When it happend I tried to ping my router address with result:

ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.105 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

where 192.168.0.105 is my address and 192.168.0.1 is router

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108  This script will collect data from your wifi setup and compile it into a wireless-info.txt file.  Copy the contents and paste at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL from it

Comment: here is that link while it was working correct (internet was running):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10598946/

Comment: Do you know how to change the settings on the router?

Comment: I can log in to router.. what should I change there?

Comment: Edited answer to update.

Comment: I'm preparing for change from WEP... but how should this help me in my problem of still logout and cannot connect back to wifi? on previous laptop and same router it was working correctly and I've around 8 devices connected to the router and no of them has same problem as this new laptop

Comment: If you leave the backports loaded and change to WPA2, it should work well.  It seems that every question that used something other than WPA2 for encryption, changing to WPA2 played a part in fixing the issue.  It could be a Linux issue since TKIP is just a little better than an open network and will slow the transfer speeds

Comment: I changed from WEP to WPA2 and still there is same problem.. When I select my wifi during everything i'm connected it will reconnect me withou problems.. but when this mysterious thing happend I can't reconnect anymore without rebooting

Comment: My last trick `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` reboot

Comment: so far I didn't use your script.. I edited my question with new findings, maybe this could help.. isn't there any problem with IPv6 or somethinf similar?

Comment: You could use Network Manager to set IPv6 settings to ignore

Comment: It looks like it wasn't problem of IPv6.. but your code echo ... seems to work since from the time I used it it didn't happen so you could put it as correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change settings on Firewall?
If yes then change the setting for OUTCOMING to ALLOW as you can see on the image:

[image]