# Wireless card disconecting

Tags: wireless

From what I can see there is an awful lot about this online already.  I have tried a few solutions that people have put up (one of them ended with me having to re-install the OS).

So I have a new laptop built by the people at pcspecialist.co.uk

Anyhow a lshw displays the following:

```
mark-w54-55su1-suw
description: Computer
width: 64 bits
capabilities: vsyscall32
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   physical id: 0
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 7901MiB
 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4712MQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 800MHz
      capacity: 800MHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cpufreq
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 06
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 06
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:44 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
    *-multimedia:0
         description: Audio device
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 06
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:47 memory:f7e14000-f7e17fff
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:40 memory:f7e00000-f7e0ffff
    *-communication
         description: Communication controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
         resources: irq:45 memory:f7e1e000-f7e1e00f
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:f7e1c000-f7e1c3ff
    *-multimedia:1
         description: Audio device
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:46 memory:f7e10000-f7e13fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:df200000-df3fffff ioport:df400000(size=2097152)
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 00
            serial: 30:10:b3:b3:1f:ec
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.13.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff
       *-generic
            description: Unassigned class
            product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            version: 01
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
            resources: irq:42 memory:f7c15000-f7c15fff memory:f7c00000-f7c0ffff
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
            logical name: eth0
            version: 12
            serial: 80:fa:5b:0c:3f:ac
            size: 10Mbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:41 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7c14000-f7c14fff memory:f7c10000-f7c13fff
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:f7e1b000-f7e1b3ff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: HM86 Express LPC Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:43 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7e1a000-f7e1a7ff
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:f7e19000-f7e190ff ioport:f040(size=32)
 *-scsi
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: CDDVDW SU-208FB
         vendor: TSSTcorp
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: TC00
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

An iwconfig show the following:

```
mark@mark-W54-55SU1-SUW:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"NETGEARPUR"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:1E:2A:1F:80:14   
      Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:17   Missed beacon:0
```

I even thought that a Kernel upgrade might help, however it doesn't seem to have helped out at all:

```
 uname -a
 Linux mark-W54-55SU1-SUW 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:06:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The only temp solution I seem to have is running:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But even this doesn't seem to be really working at the moment.  I had to restart the network manager just to write this post!

Any ideas would be most welcomed.  I do wonder if I would be better of down-grading OS.
Thanks in advance,

Mark.

Comment: Have you tried the 3.19 kernel backports?

Comment: No I have not tried to backport to 3.19. Would this solution get me there [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/596797/wifi-stop-working-after-while-on-ubuntu-14-04-2/596822#596822

Comment: That would be one and if it doesn't work it is easy to uninstall

Comment: Ok I will try it out and see how it goes.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Jeremy31 So I tried out the solution backporting to Kernel 3.19.  However this has not resolved the problem.  My connection still hangs up quite a lot, and even running 'sudo service network-manger restart' does not sort out the problem.  In the end my only solution seems to be a reboot.  Less than ideal with most people reliance on a stable network connection.  I tried looking in the syslog, there seems to be something going on

Comment: A bit strange I followed the instructions on the url I posted, but after doing a uname -r I am left with '3.13.0-46-generic'  which seems quite old...

Comment: Can you copy some of the odd stuff from syslog and paste at paste.ubuntu.com and add the URL?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have pasted some of the syslog onto paste.ubuntu which can be accessed at [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10612311/) I was using a firewall, which I have now disabled.  I don't like the idea of running a system without a firewall, but it does seem more stable.  I was using the gufw.  Any recommendations for others?

Comment: I let my wifi router to take care of firewall and it does very well.  UFW has a habit of blocking a lot of needed traffic to maintain a network connection

Comment: I fully uninstalled it.  However I am still getting the problem.  I have pasted the syslog from the time that it went wrong [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10612713/)  I tried to restart the network-manager but after the restart my connection was made, but it was still slow.  So I had to reboot the system fully in order to get a connection.  Its really starting to puzzle me as to what wrong...maybe its just 14.04 would be better off going back to a previous verion?

Comment: Is "all users may connect to this network" checked in network manager settings

Comment: Yes that is ticked for the connection in the network manager settings.

Comment: I guess no one has any solutions for me :(

Comment: I would file a bug report @ https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu so this can get fixed