# Wifi stops working randomly after a while on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I shifted from windows to ubuntu for first time on HP r-15 laptop and dual booted ubuntu 14.04 LTS with windows 8.1.But i am having problem with wifi.I can connect to wifi without any problem but after a while it randomly stops working but it is showing that i am connected.When i try to reconnect,it looks like it is trying to reconnect but never do.Only solution for this is to reboot the laptop  and everything starts working fine for some time.
I read some same questions like that but that are none of my use.
I am a beginner in linux.
Thanks for help in advance.
Edit - this was the output of the command suggested by Pilot6

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: When it fails, run `dmesg`. There may be an informative error message for you. Also, see if running `sudo service network-manager restart` instead of rebooting fixes it for a while.

Comment: working fine for me... sorry but don't know how to mark this answer as accepted

Comment: You can find the answer here - http://askubuntu.com/a/687127/380774